# How do i run rest of the code out of a loop

Tags: python, if-statement

Look in my code how can i do that

```
a = int(input("enter a number"))
if a == 5:
    # from here i want to continue below code
else:
   print("a is not 5")
   exit()

#code is here
```

what i have already tried:

1. putting it empty

```
if a == 5:
else:
   print("a is not 5")
   exit()

#code is here
```

2. putting a comment

```
if a == 5:
    # from here i want to continue below code
else:
   print("a is not 5")
   exit()

#code is here
```

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: oh sorry i meant in loop also how to exit to code

Comment: What if you remove the `if` and change `else` to `if a != 5:`?

Comment: even better: replace all with `a = 5` (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simple!

use `pass`

```
a = int(input("enter a number"))
if a == 5:
    pass:
else:
   print("a is not 5")
   exit()

#code is here
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple!

```py
a = int(input("enter a number"))

if a != 5:
  print("a is not 5")
  exit()
```

If you really want to do nothing in a certain case, use `pass`. For example:

```py
# Works for functions
def do_nothing():
  pass

# ...and for if/else clauses
if what_to_do == 'nothing':
  pass
else:
  do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `if` condition you should write expected response if the condition is true. If the condition is false then   `else` condition will be executed.

```
if a == 5:
  print("a is 5")
   exit()

else:
 print("a is not 5")
   exit()
```